# how to use strpos with special characters, hyphen

Tags: php

I'd like to run a `strpos` with those strings:

```
<?php
echo strpos("TEE-SHIRT DANI","TEE-SHIRT DANI – SAILOR STRIPE STONE
");
?>
```

but it returns false.

In the end, I need to run a test of this kind `if ( (strpos($var1, $var2) !== false)) {...`

Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: I see no "special characters" here, unless you mean that space and hyphen are "special" because they're not letters? PHP doesn't care in the slightest.

Answer (score 1):

The variables are switched: [as the manual says](https://www.php.net/strpos), the "haystack" (the string to search *in*) comes first, and the "needle" (the string to search *for*) comes second.

Instead of:

```
if ( (strpos($currenttitle, $productname) !== false)) {
```

You want:

```
if ( (strpos($productname, $currenttitle) !== false)) {
```

or in your example:

```
    echo strpos("TEE-SHIRT DANI – SAILOR STRIPE STONE
", "TEE-SHIRT DANI");
```

Comment: no it's right order, my code is like this. but I am interested in the example above with "T-SHIRT...

Comment: @Louis No, really, [read the manual carefully](https://www.php.net/strpos): the "haystack" (the string to search *in*) comes first, and the "needle" (the string to search *for*) comes second. A short string will never contain a longer string.